# Mirroring some selected folder(s) in a private repository into a public repository

Tags: git, github

In the company, we are developing an enterprise version on top of the already existing open-source edition of our product.

For practical purpose, we would like to have the codebase of both the enterprise and open-source edition on a **single monolithic git repository** to keep the development process simple. Internally, this is how we would like to structure our codebase:

```
* main-repository-private
    /folder-for-open-source-edition
    /folder-enterprise-edition
```

However, we want people to be able to contribute to the open source software. This includes making PRs, creating issues, forking the codebase, etc.

This would mean that while we need to keep the enterprise codebase private, the open-source needs to be in a public repository.

We could create two completely separate repository, however as I've stated, this makes development hard since there are often changes on the open-source which may affect enterprise, as the former is depended upon by the later.

This is what we're thinking to do, which we're not sure if it is possible technically:

*Can we create a main repository (private), and mirror one or more selected folders within that repository, onto a public repository?*

```
* main-repository-private
    /folder-for-open-source-edition
    /folder-enterprise-edition

* open-source-repository-public --> mirrors "main-repository-private/folder-for-open-source-edition"
```

Comment: Or, how to implement Subversion's externals in Git. I'd love to see a good answer to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is that you create a private repository for the enterprise edition. Create another public repository for the open source edition.
Add a submodule in the private repository to the open source edition repository.

This way you can decide when you upgrade the enterprise edition to the new version in the open source edition and get the benefit of having the source of your open source edition inside the same directory structure for the enterprise edition.

Be sure to study how submodules work before doing this, so you know how to handle a submodule. Short it's just a repository inside another repository pointing out at which commit the submodule repo source will be taken from. You can work inside that submodule directory as if you were inside another repository.